# vba Excel Paste Values: automatic: Error 1004 manual: OK

Tags: vba, excel, loops, copy-paste

strange problem:
I read some Values from a sheet with a loop and paste them to another sheet.

I have a Control Module which calls one module after the other one.

My Problem: If I do the Call via control Module I run into the runtime error 1004.

When I start the macro manually it is no problem and everythin works fine..

This is my code:

```
    [...]
rngname = 3
    temp = 1
    Do Until Cells(lngRow, 1).Value = "test"

        lngLastRowOfSection = Cells(lngRow, 1).End(xlDown).Row

        Set slcFind = Range(Cells(lngRow, 1), Cells(lngLastRowOfSection, 1))
        slcFind.Copy
        Set targetRange = Worksheets("Node Canister VPD").Cells(1, 1)

         targetRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True


        lngRow = Cells(lngLastRowOfSection, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        If lngRow >= Rows.Count Then Exit Do

    Loop

    lngRow = 1

    rngname = 3
    i = 2
    Do Until Cells(lngRow, 1).Value = "test"

        lngLastRowOfSection = Cells(lngRow, 1).End(xlDown).Row

        Set slcFind = Range(Cells(lngRow, 2), Cells(lngLastRowOfSection, 2))
        slcFind.Copy
        Set targetRange = Worksheets("Node Canister VPD").Cells(i, 1)

         targetRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True


        lngRow = Cells(lngLastRowOfSection, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        If lngRow >= Rows.Count Then Exit Do
    i = i + 1
    Loop

[...]
```

Has anyone an idea?
This part of the code is marked:

```
targetRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
```

Best Regards,
Kalain

Comment: explicitly define your objects to their parent. For example `Cells(lngRow, 1)` is not tied to any specific sheet. So define to the specific sheet. `Worksheets(1).Cells(lngRow,1)` ... for example.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. But its no solution for my problem. I dont get it...Manual start: no problem. Automatic start: Runtime Error 1004...

Comment: Before being so quick to dismiss it as a solution, please implement it fully and see if it works. When you don't explicitly declare objects to parents the code can behave in seemingly very funny ways. Specifically, it will act on whatever sheet happens to be active at the moment the line of code is run, which may not be the one you suspect. Sometimes the problem is not where you think it lies.

Comment: I'm with Scott on this one. Knock out what at first glance seem obvious issues.  Fairly certain he or I would first work to refactor your VBA to be as explicit as possible with regards which object touches which sheet/cell BEFORE even running the code.

Comment: I implented it....but wrong..I'm a newbie in vba scripting. But I'm able to learn :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scott Holtzman is correct, define your worksheet when setting ranges.  I was able to recreate the bug by having 1 sheet with valid data, the sheet to paste and another entirely blank sheet.  When I ran the macro from the valid sheet, it was fine, when I ran it with the blank sheet activated it tries to transpose a blank column to a row.  Excel sheets have more columns then rows, so it crashes because it can't fit.

Try using this, change "First" to whatever your source sheet is called.

```
Sub test()

Dim Other As New Worksheet
Set Other = Worksheets("First")
lngrow = 1
rngname = 3
    temp = 1
    Do Until other.Cells(lngrow, 1).Value = "test"

        lngLastRowOfSection = Other.Cells(lngrow, 1).End(xlDown).Row

        Set slcFind = Range(Other.Cells(lngrow, 1), Other.Cells(lngLastRowOfSection, 1))
        slcFind.Copy
        Set targetRange = Worksheets("Node Canister VPD").Cells(1, 1)

         targetRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True


        lngrow = Other.Cells(lngLastRowOfSection, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        If lngrow >= Rows.Count Then Exit Do

    Loop

    lngrow = 1

    rngname = 3
    i = 2
    Do Until Other.Cells(lngrow, 1).Value = "test"

        lngLastRowOfSection = Other.Cells(lngrow, 1).End(xlDown).Row

        Set slcFind = Range(Other.Cells(lngrow, 2), Other.Cells(lngLastRowOfSection, 2))
        slcFind.Copy
        Set targetRange = Worksheets("Node Canister VPD").Cells(i, 1)

         targetRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True


        lngrow = Other.Cells(lngLastRowOfSection, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        If lngrow >= Rows.Count Then Exit Do
    i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charme! I used the definition of the worksheet on the wrong places..shame on me..